# Apache tomcat how to create a link to a url

Tags: tomcat

I have the following default-ssl.conf

ProxyPass /comunes/ http://mapapre.mapa.es/comunes/

In DES environment.

Now I want to create it in my local Apache tomcat.

I modified the file server.xml.

I added

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

        <Context docBase="/comunes/" path="http://mapapre.mapa.es/comunes/" />

      </Host>
```

When I stat the server, I get a error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [D:\apache-tomcat-9.0.27\webapps\comunes] is not valid
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.createMainResourceSet(StandardRoot.java:752)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:709)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
```

How have I create this link in my local apache?

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [Context documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html) you'll find that you have a fundamental misunderstanding of the `path` and `docBase` attributes that you use.

> docBase
>
> The Document Base (also known as the Context Root) directory for this
>   web application, or the pathname to the web application archive file
>   (if this web application is being executed directly from the WAR
>   file). You may specify an absolute pathname for this directory or WAR
>   file, or a pathname that is relative to the appBase directory of the
>   owning Host.
>
> The value of this field must not be set unless the Context element is
>   defined in server.xml or the docBase is not located under the Host's
>   appBase.
>
> If a symbolic link is used for docBase then changes to the symbolic
>   link will only be effective after a Tomcat restart or by undeploying
>   and redeploying the context. A context reload is not sufficient.

and

> path
>
> The context path of this web application, which is matched against the
>   beginning of each request URI to select the appropriate web
>   application for processing. All of the context paths within a
>   particular Host must be unique. If you specify a context path of an
>   empty string (""), you are defining the default web application for
>   this Host, which will process all requests not assigned to other
>   Contexts.
>
> This attribute must only be used when statically defining a Context in
>   server.xml. In all other circumstances, the path will be inferred from
>   the filenames used for either the .xml context file or the docBase.
>
> Even when statically defining a Context in server.xml, this attribute
>   must not be set unless either the docBase is not located under the
>   Host's appBase or both deployOnStartup and autoDeploy are false. If
>   this rule is not followed, double deployment is likely to result.

Apart from that, you probably only need to deploy your webapplication in tomcat's `webapps/` directory with the name `comunes.war` (or in the directory `webapps/comunes`), without any static configuration in server.xml.